# Cut and replace specific column from a list of file

Tags: sed, cut

```
41703
10002
30003
40002
40000
20203
20203
30100
50000
50000
50000
50000
70700
70600
```

I have this file. and i Want output as

```
4.17.3
1.0.2
3.0.3
4.0.2
4.0.0
2.2.3
2.2.3
3.1.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
7.7.0
7.6.0
```

I'm working on solaris machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1.\2.\3/' -e 's/\.0/./g' file
4.17.3
1.0.2
3.0.3
4.0.2
4.0.0
2.2.3
2.2.3
3.1.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
7.7.0
7.6.0
```

The first `sed` substitution creates `x.yy.zz` from `xyyzz`.  It does this by capturing the three groups of characters in separate capture groups (the `\(.\)` and the two `\(..\)` where each dot matches a single character), and then inserts these again with dots in-between.

The second substitution removes any zero immediately after a dot.

Comment: Perfect!!!!! That's the thing which was all i needed..But need one explaination. Can you explain how first sed is converting xyyzz -> x.yy.zz pattern?

Comment: @UtkarshMishra See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ printf "%d.%d.%d\n", substr($1,1,1), substr($1,2,3)/10, substr($1,5) }' file
```

- `substr(string, start [, length ])` - Return a `length`-character-long substring of `string`, starting at character number `start`.

The output:

```
4.17.3
1.0.2
3.0.3
4.0.2
4.0.0
2.2.3
2.2.3
3.1.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
7.7.0
7.6.0
```

---

If GNU `awk` is supported a shorter way would be as follows:

```
awk -v FS="" '{ print $1, ($2$3$4)/10, $5 }' OFS='.' file
```

- `FS=""` - If the value is the null string (`""`), then each character in the record becomes a separate field.

Comment: With GNU awk I guess one could also set the fieldwidths explicitly e.g. `gawk '{printf("%d.%d.%d\n",$1,$2,$3)}' FIELDWIDTHS='1 2 2' file`

Comment: @steeldriver, yes, that would also be a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed solution

```
sed -r 's/\B(..)/.\1./; s/\.0/./g' input.txt
```

**\B** - Matches everywhere but on a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the left and the character to the right are either both “word” characters or both “non-word” characters.

The `sed` solution without GNU features

```
sed -r 's/(.)(..)/\1.\2./; s/\.0/./g' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
4.17.3
1.0.2
3.0.3
4.0.2
4.0.0
2.2.3
2.2.3
3.1.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
5.0.0
7.7.0
7.6.0
```